# Load a facebook post inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, web

Is there a way to load the first post from a facebook page into my website?

I know .load() does the trick, but not for other websites. Maybe .get() can be used somehow, but I don't know if there's a way to use just a part of the page.

Comment: With "first" you mean the latest post?

Comment: Have you tried with Facebook's api?

Comment: Yes by "first" I mean latest.
No I have not tried with Facebook's api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/page/feed) to fetch the latest post id:

```
FB.api(
    "/{page-id}/feed",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        var latestPostId = response.data[0].id.split('_')[1];
      }
    }
);
```

Then you can embed the post dynamically like this:

```
// Create an element, you could use jQuery for this as well.
var embed = document.createElement('div');
embed.className = 'fb-post';
embed.setAttribute('data-href', 'https://www.facebook.com/{page_id}/posts/{post_id}/');

// Place it on the page somewhere.
document.body.appendChild(embed);

// You might have to let FB parse your page again.
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use it, as it gives me an error: "FB is not defined". I couldn't find how to implement the api.

Comment: This does not work right out of the box. You'll have to [integrate the Facebook API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart) on your page and do some groundwork ([get an API Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/)) to actually make the request happen.